# Mono for android - How connect to pc for copy file

Tags: mono, xamarin.android

I would want my application connect to pc and copy a file (we know the path in the pc) to the tablet.
But I know connect an application-tablet to an application-pc with socket but there I don't want use socket because the pc musn't listen.

It is possible ??

Comment: Why won't you open an FTP on the PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a server on your PC which will allow you to access the file system on it. Even if the device you are connecting with your PC is in host mode, the PC would not know what to do as it, itself is in host mode.

So you have a couple of options:

1. Use an existing service such as Dropbox, FTP or similar to synchronize files between the phone and PC.
2. Write your own service to pull the file from you phone. Here I guess you could use [`adb`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to do the actual file transfer.
3. Create Windows/SMB/CIFS shared folder on your PC and access files through the network, maybe [UNC paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#UNC_in_Windows) will work?
4. Black voodoo magic.